# Returning the row of an input value if it is within a range of two Columns in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe formatted like this in pandas.

```
Building ID    Column 2    Column 3
Building 1     100         200
Building 2     201         302
Building 3     303         404
....
```

I want to be able to enter a value, and if the value is between the numbers in Column 2 and 3, I'd like to return the associated Building ID.

So my desired output would be like this

```
Input Number: 205



Building ID    Column 2    Column 3
Building 2     201         302
```

or even just

```
Input Number: 205

Building ID
Building 2
```

I'm not sure if I need a conditional statement, or something along the lines of an inbetween function to get my desired results. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `between` by using `df.loc` and having two conditions, one where the `input_number` is greater than or equal to `Column 2` and one where it is less than or equal to `Column 3`

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Building ID': {0: 'Building 1', 1: 'Building 2', 2: 'Building 3'},
 'Column 2': {0: 100, 1: 201, 2: 303},
 'Column 3': {0: 200, 1: 302, 2: 404}})

input_number = int(input('Number'))

df.loc[(input_number >= df['Column 2']) & (input_number <= df['Column 3'])]

# or if you prefer the built in greater than less than methods:
# df.loc[(df['Column 2'].le(input_number)) & (df['Column 3'].ge(input_number))]
```

Output

```
   Building ID  Column 2    Column 3
1   Building 2       201         302
```

Comment: Thanks! This answered my question. Another question I have is would there be a way to create it as a function? Such as :```def function(num) return (num)?```

Comment: I would ask that in a new question so that others can see it.

Answer (score 0):

data.csv file:

```
Building ID,Column 2,Column 3
Building 1,100,200
Building 2,201,302
Building 3,303,404
```

code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("data.csv")
print(df)
number = 205
newdf = df[(df['Column 2'] <= number) & (number <= df['Column 3'])]
print(newdf)
```